# Why does csc2.exe exit with an error code with the use of the dynamic keyword?

Tags: c#, com, callback

```
    public void SearchApps(string query, object callback)
    {
        dynamic callbackFunc = callback;
        ThreadManager.QueryGamesAsync(query, mainForm.Portal, log, 
            (list) =>
            {
                string[] strList = new string[list.Length];
                for(int i = 0; i < strList.Length; i++)
                {
                    strList[i] = list[i].Uid;
                }
                string data = json.Serialize(strList);
                callbackFunc(data);
            });
    }
```

This method causes csc2.exe to exit with code 1 thus I can't compile it. Any idea what's wrong ? The method is part of the ScriptingObject of a browser control. That's why the callback is dynamic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to reference "Microsoft.CSharp" in order to use dynamic.